# Is the origin of the term "blackleg" racist?

Tags: etymology

A **blackleg** is defined as:

> a person who continues working when fellow workers are on strike

When did this term originate? Does it's origin have racist connotations?

Comment: This term is uncommon in the U.S., where such a worker is usually a *scab*.

Comment: @choster - this is also true in the UK, where the term apparently originates.

Comment: I've never heard the term before either (US) - in what context did you see it? What gives it potentially racist connotations?

Comment: Note that a word that doesn't have racist origins may still have racist connotations today: see the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). (Honestly, I've never heard this term before so I've no idea if it has racist connotations or not.)

Answer (score 30):

Its etymology seems to be without racist connotations; at least according to the website for *National Coal Mining Museum for England*:

> **Blackleg**
>   Term for a worker who breaks
>   a strike and continues working. The name comes from working miners trying to hide the fact that they had been working could be found out if their trousers were rolled up: they would have black legs. See scab, strike breaker.
>   — [The 1984-5 Miners Strike Resource](https://www.ncm.org.uk/downloads/104/The_1984-5_Miners__Strike_Resource__hi_res_.pdf)

On the other hand, [wordsmith.org](http://wordsmith.org/words/blackleg.html) says

> noun:
>   1. One who works while other workers are on strike.
>   2. A swindler, especially in games such as gambling.
>   3. One of various diseases of plants or cattle.
>
> ETYMOLOGY:
>   It’s unclear how the term came to be employed for a strikebreaker. Earliest documented use: 1722.

... so it's hard to be 100% sure!

Comment: I would suggest you fill out your first sentence. Exactly what you mean by "No." is not clear. I understand you to be referring to racism, but others might not "get it".

Comment: @CorvusB Cheers,  I've updated the answer.

Comment: This answer seems to support the idea that the origin is not racist.

Comment: "strikebreaker" I think is the only term I've ever heard in the US

Comment: "Strikebreaker" means something totally different. It isn't a worker who crosses strike lines.

Answer (score 8):

There are different assumptions about the origin of the term used to refer to strikers who cheat going to work.

According to the following, the meaning derives from the bird rook known for its rapacious appetite and its black legs:

> - The expression ***[blackleg](http://www.englishgrammar.org/origin-word-blackleg/)*** originated from the bird rook. As we all know, this bird is black in colour and has got black legs. Rooks are very cunning and they know how to steal food. Needless to say, few people like them. Even today, the term rook is sometimes used to refer to a person who takes advantage of gullible individuals. Since rooks have black legs, cheats are also called blacklegs. ***As time went by, this expression began to be used to refer to workers who cheat by going to work when their fellow employers are on strike.*** (English Grammar)

Another assumption is that the expression originated among  ***[coal mine strikers](http://cjewords.blogspot.it/2012/03/blackleg.html):***

> - ***The term is said to have come from strikes in the coal mines. Those who were on strike had washed and brushed up after their last trip down the mine and therefore anyone covered in coal dust was a strike-breaker - a blackleg.*** The derogatory term scab is also used for such people. It is not a direct synonym of strike-breaker since a blackleg is specifically someone who works at a job while his colleagues are on strike. (Words, Words and Phrases)

Comment: So you're saying it's not racist.

Comment: @smci - it appears that it is not, but that is mainly a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: @JOSH A previous answer dates this to 1722 in the UK.  This is before any involvement of Africans in the UK workforce, and specifically in the mining industry.  As such, it belongs with blackface Molly Dancers or the insult "blackguard" in having no racist origins or connotations, in spite of what a superficial look might suggest.

Comment: @Graham -   The 1771/2 early usage  was not originally referred to a strikebreaker, which is later, probably mid.19th century. Blackleg:  *"swindler," especially in equestrian events, 1771, from black (adj.) + leg (n.), but the exact signification is uncertain.* (Etymonline).

Comment: @JOSH Without any significant African presence in the UK though, this is clearly unrelated to skin colour.  So it isn't "personal opinion" that it's not racist - it's the only realistic conclusion supported by the evidence.

Comment: @Graham - the fact is that its original usage, (swindler) from which probably the meaning of  strikebreaker derives, is of unknown origin and possibly related to equestrian events. This leaves room for speculations and we can't confirm or rule out  other possible origins. Anyway, I agree, that from what we "know" a racist origin does not apprear to be the case.

Comment: @JOSH multiple theories of origin are discussed in this 1889 dictionary: https://books.google.com/books?id=ZY8VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22blackleg%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjchvz4qeTPAhWD7B4KHeM7Ax4Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22blackleg%22%20dictionary&f=false

Comment: from where are these poorly-written quotes taken, by the way?

Answer (score 4):

From yet another source ([unfortunately unavailable](http://graham.thewebtailor.co.uk/archives/000069.html)):

> 'Blackleg' dates from the very early 1700s. Eric Partridge gives
>   alternative uses and origins. By 1722 it is certainly being used as a
>   description of a disease affecting the legs of sheep and cattle.
>   Tempting though it is to suggest that the earliest organised wage
>   workers, the wool combers, who were noted for trade union militancy,
>   used the term there is no direct evidence that this was so.
>
> Another version of its origins has it as a gaming term, dating from
>   1771. According to this view, blacklegs were firstly "turf-swindlers", the name coming from a fashion amongst them for wearing a certain kind
>   of black boot. Another, related possibility is that gamecocks, used in
>   the then very popular `sport' of cock-fighting, were invariably the
>   possessors of black legs.
>
> Yet another version of its origin is supposed to be from the mining
>   industry. The term was certainly used in miners' songs of the 1830's.
>   (See A L Lloyd's "Come All Ye Bold Miners - ballads and songs of the
>   coalfields" [1978] ", published by Lawrence and Wishart, for various
>   examples.) This raises the question of whether it is a word special to
>   the mining industry in origin. For this was the period when the word
>   "blacksheep" was current. It has often been suggested that in the
>   context of the coal industry the word `blacklegs' has a double edge to
>   it. For, in the days before pithead baths, a working miner in a strike
>   situation could easily be found by the simple expedient of lifting his
>   trouser leg to discover his own leg blackened by coal dust! This seems
>   a little fanciful, whilst there is no academic backing for the notion.
>   After all, mining strikes took place in closed communities where there
>   was little chance of discovering a wayward spirit. There could however
>   be some derisory value involved here and the sporting origin -
>   especially of cock fighting - would fit the social milieu of the
>   collier better.
>
> From this account it may be readily seen that no racist intent or
>   connotation is involved in the term "blackleg", arising from the use
>   of the word `black' as a negative force. Nonetheless, modern dislike
>   of the term arises from the method whereby the word "black" is
>   frequently used in this way- as in black arts or witchcraft, black
>   mood, black day, black outlook, etc. etc.

Sidenote: In Swedish it is a similar word word for this "svartfot" (black foot), probably translated from the English word.

Funnily enough(?) there are other racist sounding words for similar issues that aren't either. "Gulingar" (Yellows), comes from employer friendly unions that had was called The Yellow Union. And we also have "bruntungor" (brown tounges) which is a euphemism for "kiss ass" as you might imagine why.

Comment: From here? https://www.flashback.org/p3228471

Comment: Oh, yes. Forgot to add the intermediate source.

Answer (score 0):

In Swedish it is "svart-fot" (literally "black feet")

3) [jfr eng. black-leg] (vard.) till 7 b, ss. nedsättande benämning på person som arbetar på blockerad arbetsplats, strejkbrytare; i sht i pl. SvD 14⁄12 1924, s. 12. Varje dag pågår människosmuggling på Bromma flygplats. Fyra värdinnor, utpekade som ”svartfötter” och strejkbrytare, förs i bilstafetter från planen till någon grind som demonstranter just då inte bevakar och vidare till hemliga övernattningslägenheter. Därs. 23⁄8 1975

source: http://www.saob.se/artikel/?seek=svartfot&pz=2#U_S14717_213322

Comment: You need to add the translation